# Jenkins publish over CIFS plugin hanging

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cifs

A security vulnerability forced me to update my CIFS plugin, but now the latest version hangs when publishing over CIFS. I found this issue which describes my problem.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49211

Does anyone have a workaround outside of manually copying artifacts until this issue is resolved?